# Laravel checking if name is already in use throws error

Tags: php, laravel

When I'm trying to check if name is already in use I get error like this: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'feknaz' for key 'name'

Well it says that it's a duplicate. But how to make it look like every other error in laravel ? How to show it like "This name is already taken". I don't know how to make this for that one field. This is my code:

RegistersUsers.php:

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
     if (User::where('name', '=', Input::get('name'))->count() > 0) {
       return redirect('registruotis')->withErrors(['msg', 'The Message']);
    }       
    return redirect('registruotis')->withErrors($validator);
}
```

Register.blade.php:

```
@if (count($errors))
<div id="error-box" class="alert alert-danger center-block" style="width: 350px">
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

**I SOLVED IT**

I just needed to put this:

```
 if (User::where('name', '=', Input::get('name'))->count() > 0) {
   return redirect('registruotis')->withErrors(['msg', 'The Message']);
```

before `if ($validator->fails())`

Comment: please post the solution as answer, not as edit of question. And then accept it by yourself. Such behavior is clear for everyone and actually explicitly encouraged by SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

The validator automatically handles this for you:

```
$validate = Validator:make(array(
    ....
    'name' => 'unique:users,name'
));
```

This will produce the correct error when the `name` already exists in the table `users` on the column `name`. You can customize the error message if that's something you need to do.

Comment: @feknez Prior to your `$validator->fails()` check.

Comment: `Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Validator' not found` I get this. Should I include Validator ?

Comment: So I included `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Validator;` and I still get `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Validator` not found

Comment: @feknaz And does `RegistersUsers.php` extend `Controller` ?

Comment: No, it doesn't extend a controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102746/discussion-between-ohgodwhy-and-feknaz).

Comment: Problem still not fixed